# Sending multipart/mixed request in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-api, multipart, google-search-console, google-search-api

i want to send multipart request to Google Search Console as described in here
https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v1/how-tos/batch#batch-example-request

I'm looking for any help how to send request like this in JavaScript. I'm struggling with this for couple days and i'm running out of ideas.

My code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'https://www.googleapis.com/batch/webmasters/v3');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + access_token);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Host', 'www.googleapis.com');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/mixed; boundary=batch_foobarbaz');                            
var data = [];       
data.push('\n');
data.push('--batch_foobarbaz');
data.push('Content-Type: application/http');

data.push('\n');
data.push('GET /webmasters/v3/sites/' + siteAdress);  
data.push('\n');
 
data.push('--batch_foobarbaz');           
data.push('Content-Type: application/http');

data.push('\n');
data.push('GET /webmasters/v3/sites/' + siteAdress2);
data.push('\n');   
data.push('--batch_foobarbaz--');
           
var payload = data.join('\n');        
xhr.send(payload);
```

My request look like this

```
--batch_foobarbaz
Content-Type: application/http


GET /webmasters/v3/sites/https%3A%2F%2Fdomain.pl%2F

--batch_foobarbaz
Content-Type: application/http


GET /webmasters/v3/sites/https%3A%2F%2Fdomain.pl%2F

--batch_foobarbaz--
```

Response i reciving

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Failed to parse batch request, error: Failed in parsing HTTP headers: (64 bytes redacted). Received batch body: (0) bytes redacted",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Comment: Anyone? I can pay ;)